# Java 8 Update 25 Deployment - Disable Auto Update using MST

Tags: java, deployment

Good morning all,

I have been tasked with investigating a possible rollout of Java 8.  Ideally I do not want this out on PC's in my enterprise but I may have no option.  A lot of testing needs to be done.

Our current version is Java 7 Update 67, and I successfully deployed Java and using an MST, I disabled the Java AutoUpdate feature, which gets rid of the unwanted prompt "Your Java Version is Out Of Date - Select Update, Block, Later"

I have tried applying the same config to my Java 8 MST, although some of the switch names that control the auto update have changed to the Java v7 MST, the theory should work the same.  The MST is applying and I can see my changes, yet I am still prompted with the "Your Java version is out of date"

I have looked up numerous sites that have dealt with Java 8 deployment, yet I still cannot get it to work.

I can't see where I can attach my MST, but I have the switches applied below

Any help will be much appreciated

Cheers
Larry

AUTO_UPDATE = 0

EULA=0

JU  0

REBOOT  0

STATIC  0

WEB_ANALYTICS   0

[Changed properties]

AUTOUPDATECHECK 0

JAVAUPDATE  0

[New registry entries]

a_notifyreg 2   SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy    NotifyDownload  #0  jz

a_updatereg 2   SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy    EnableJavaUpdate    #0  jz

a_updatereg0    2   SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Update\Policy    EnableAutoUpdateCheck   #0  jz